# How to rewrite the TVEventHandler of React Native using React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In the React Native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-apple-tv), the usage of `TVEventHandler` is given as:

```
var TVEventHandler = require('TVEventHandler');

class Game2048 extends React.Component {
  _tvEventHandler: any;

  _enableTVEventHandler() {
    this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function(cmp, evt) {
      if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(2)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(1)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(0)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(3)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'playPause') {
        cmp.restartGame();
      }
    });
  }

  _disableTVEventHandler() {
    if (this._tvEventHandler) {
      this._tvEventHandler.disable();
      delete this._tvEventHandler;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._enableTVEventHandler();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._disableTVEventHandler();
  }

}
```

How should this code be rewritten using React Hooks? I can't figure out this particular line: `this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function(cmp, evt) {`, especially the `this` part.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work, hopefully can help you as well:

```
const App = () => {
  const _tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();

  const _enableTVEventHandler = () => {
    _tvEventHandler.enable(this, function (cmp, evt) {
      if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
        console.log(evt.eventType);
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
        console.log(evt.eventType);
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
        console.log(evt.eventType);
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
        console.log(evt.eventType);
      }
    });
  };

  const _disableTVEventHandler = () => {
    if (_tvEventHandler) {
      _tvEventHandler.disable();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    _enableTVEventHandler();
    return () => _disableTVEventHandler();
  });

  return null;
}
```

Comment: facing this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Comment: You always create brandnew instance of TVEventHandler and there is no dependency array in useEffect

Answer (score 1):

It's because TVEventHandler and other components for build android tv deleted from react native core. So you should run this command and it's converted your react native to tv os:

`yarn add react-native@npm:react-native-tvos@latest`

And your react native version after install `react-native-tvos` :

[image]

Now TVEventHandler and another tv build components added to your react native if you checked `./node_modules/react_native/Libraries/components`